# Ao desconstruir um one-liner baseado em perl ocorre o erro "Can't modify single ref constructor in scalar assignment"

Tags: md5, perl

```
export dev2='/dev/sdb';
perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{\$/=\1024};print md5(\$_)' $dev2
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> Can't modify single ref constructor in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "1024}"
>   BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Alguma sugestão do que estou fazendo errado? Estou me baseando em https://serverfault.com/questions/27397/sync-lvm-snapshots-to-backup-server/168034#168034

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

não é muito claro o que pertendes fazer, mas
tenta algo como:

```
perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\1024};print md5($_)'
```

ou para ficar mais legivel:

```
perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5_hex' -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\1024};print "\n$.:, md5_hex($_),"\n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar enganado, mas a barra na frente do 1024 é para escapar o argumento passado para o `/root/.ssh/rsync_rsa` (conforme a [resposta no SeverFault](https://serverfault.com/a/168034)):

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/rsync_rsa $remote "
  perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{\$/=\1024};print md5(\$_)' $dev2 | lzop -c" |
  lzop -dc | perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\1024};$b=md5($_);
    read STDIN,$a,16;if ($a eq $b) {print "s"} else {print "c" . $_}' $dev1 | lzop -c |
ssh -i /root/.ssh/rsync_rsa $remote "lzop -dc |
  perl -ne 'BEGIN{\$/=\1} if (\$_ eq\"s\") {\$s++} else {if (\$s) {
    seek STDOUT,\$s*1024,1; \$s=0}; read ARGV,\$buf,1024; print \$buf}' 1<> $dev2"
```

Então no seu caso como **você não** está manando pelo *rsync_rsa* e sim digitando direto, não precisa "escapar" o numero, faça apenas isso:

```
export dev2='/dev/sdb';
perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{\$/=1024};print md5(\$_)' $dev2
```

Estou sem emulador de terminal, mas se ainda falhar é porque não precisa escapar os `$` dentro de `'...'` (não posso afirmar, faz tempo que não uso Linux/Unix):

```
export dev2='/dev/sdb';
perl -'MDigest::MD5 md5' -ne 'BEGIN{$/=1024};print md5($_)' $dev2
```